# Reported speech with pronouns 'I' and 'he/she'

Tags: reported-speech

I was wondering if I could use 'reported speech' grammar when I want to report what I said in the past.for instance,

*first:

**present:**
me:we have not met each other.
person A:yes, you are right

**later:**
me:I told you *we have not met or we had not met*

which one is correct **have not** or **had not**?

*second

**present:**
person A:they called me today and said if I don't take my parcel,they would send it back.

person B:really?

**later:**
me:person A said if he doesn't or didn't take his parcel,they would send it back.

which one is correct **doesn't** or **didn't**?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

(1) If the conversation was face-to-face, you would say later "I told you we had not met," meaning 'we had not met until then'. If the conversation was by telephone or online and you still have not met one another in person, it would be possible to use "have not".

(2) I would expect A to say "If I don't collect my parcel, they **will** send it back." How you report it later depends on whether A has collected the parcel yet!

If he has not: "A said if he doesn't collect his parcel they will send it back."

If he has: "A said if he didn't collect his parcel they would send it back, [so he went straight away]."